# Don't know how to loop a function

Tags: html, ajax

I have this HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function(){
    $( "#punti_casa" ).load( "../scoreboard/Output/Home_Score.txt" );
}); 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function(){
    $( "#punti_trasferta" ).load( "../scoreboard/Output/Away_Score.txt" );
}); 
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="interfaccia_base">
    <div class="interfaccia_top"></div>
    <div class="riga_testi_vuoto"></div>
  <div class="riga_testi_1"></div>
    <div class="riga_testi_home"></div>
    <div class="riga_testi_punti" style="margin-left: 2px;"><div id="punti_casa"></div></div>
  <div class="riga_testi_quarto"></div>
  <div class="riga_testi_punti"><div id="punti_trasferta"></div></div>
    <div class="riga_testi_away"></div>
  <div class="riga_testi_1"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I used the meta HTTP to refresh every 1 second. The problem is that in the streaming software I use, the HTML is flickering every time it refreshes.
There is maybe a way to loop the function to read at the text file and if the number inside is changed, it rewrites the content in "#punti_casa" and in "#punti_trasferta"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function loadData(){
  $( "#punti_trasferta" ).load( "../scoreboard/Output/Away_Score.txt", function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ loadData(); }, 3000); <-- 3 sec delay between reloads.
  });
}
```

You can add more intelligence to do a diff and update dom only if something changes.

Comment: it worked perfectly, i'm not a coder so i don't know a lot of stuff, i'm trying to understand things, thank you so much for the support!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use setInterval to refresh it every seconds without any stop possibility

```
window.setInterval(function(){
     $("#punti_casa").load("../scoreboard/Output/Home_Score.txt");
}, 1000);
```

If you need to stop your reload use clearInterval() it'll work fine

Comment: i'll give it a try as soon as possible, thank you so much!